# Notifying delegate about custom radio button index selection in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

I am creating a custom Radio Button on UITableViewCell. I am confused on implementing a delegate which will notify me for each button selection.

For example, in UITableView, we have a method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

It is called when a user selects the particular row. I would like to have same behavior for my option button selection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you subclass `UIButton` and use the usual target/action semantics instead of reinventing the wheel.

However, if you want to implement the delegation pattern generically, there is excellent documentation from Apple in the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) (scroll down to the section titled "Implementing a Delegate for a Custom Class").

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to observe the action that the user took. I'd create the radio button as a UIControl, and use target action to observe the user selection.

So you will want to tell the button:

```
[radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonValueDidChange:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and then implement a method that observes the action:

```
- (void)radioButtonValueDidChange:(RadioButton *)button {
// Do whatever you need to after a user selects a button.
}
```

So now the "radioButtonValueDidChange:" will be called each time the object is selected or deselected, and you can act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks dude, it helped me a lot. However I used delegation pattern in generic way and above method inside.

Comment: When you're setting up the table cell, you can use the tag variable to distinguish which radio button was changed.

radioButton.tag = indexPath.row;